# Inheritance for sorting a Linked List without clutter

Tags: c++, linked-list, polymorphism

I have a problem which seems simple, but I can't find an elegant solution for it.

I'm using a linked list which I need to sort twice:

- once on one parameter as list elements are added, and
- once on a different parameter after some processing.

The objects I store in the list inherit from an abstract list item base class.

The problem is with resorting on the second parameter. I don't want to write a pure virtual accessor for it in the list item base class, because I later store some other objects in the list which also inherit from the list item base class, but the second accessor wouldn't make sense for them.

Is there a clean solution that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you mean it's a linked list of `Derived`, or a linked list of `Base*`?

Comment: You would need to clarify a bit, maybe give an example... What do you mean "sorted on one or the other parameter"? What do you mean "parameter" here? In general, try to be a bit clearer.

Comment: @user1447786 you may want to format your question. Walls of text aren't friendly, so instead of reading it I formatted it for you. I hope others will find it easier to read now

Comment: "I later store some other objects in the list which also inherit from the list item base class, but the second accessor wouldn't make sense for them" => If they are in the same list, they also would get involved in the second sorting. Then how do you intent to get the sorting done for these items?

Comment: @sehe thank you. Sorry, this is my first post.

Comment: @Unni I first add elements to the list which are sorted as they are added, I then use them for something, and afterwards I re-sort the list. I add the other objects (which don't have the second parameter) to the list after the re-sorting.

Comment: You have answered @Unni's question, but not his point; if someone were to perform the second kind of sorting on a list containing the "other" objects, what behavior would you want? And why don't you just make a linked list of `Derived`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you've something like that :

```
 class Base {
    public:
    int getParam1() const { ... }; 
    virtual void foo() =0;  // this is an abstract class
    virtual ~Base() { ... }
 }
 class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    int getParam1() const { ... }
    int getParam2() const { ... }

 }
```

And you have a `std::list<Base*> myList` somewhere. The first time you want to sort your list, you do something like :

```
sort(list.begin(),list.end(),[](const Base*v1,const Base*v2) {
    return v1->getParam1()<v2->getParam1();
});
```

And for the second sort, you need to use something specific to the class `Derived`. You don't want to add a pure virtual accessor `getParam2()` into `Base` & implement it in `Derived`. But if you know that your list contains *only* Derived objets, you can use a cast without problem :

```
sort(list.begin(),list.end(),[](const Base*b1,const Base*b2) {
    const Derived * d1 = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(b1);
    const Derived * d2 = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(b2);

    return d1->getParam2() < d2->getParam2();
});
```

Note that if an object of your list is not a `Derived`, dynamic_cast will return `nullptr` so you can safely check it.

Comment: And if dynamic cast returns null what to do with that item in the sorting step?

Comment: It means that you're mixing Derived & non-Derived objects in your list. You could for instance always put the Derived before the non-Derived. Or if both d1 & d2 are non Derived, you can still sort using getParam1(). Anyway, this is your choice !

Comment: This works fine for me. I worked around sorting the list with the second group of objects afterwards. Thank you, and sorry for being unclear!

Answer (score 3):

Use a predicate:

```
std::list<Base*> myList; /* populate */

myList.sort([](Base * const p1, Base * const p2) -> bool
            { return static_cast<Derived*>(p1)->compare_with(*p2); }
           );
```

This assumes that during your sorting run, all elements are actually pointers to `Derived` which have a member function `foo` (doesn't even need to be virtual) which returns a bool.

You can of course adapt the details of the predicate in any way you like. You can also replace the lambda expression with a traditional, spelt-out predicate class if you are on an old compiler.

If you can't be sure that all your elements are actually of `Derived` type, then you could employ a `dynamic_cast` instead, but then you'll have to think of a way to order all the incomparable objects. In that case it might be better to first partition your range into those things which are `Derived` and those which aren't, and only sort the former.

Comment: Shouldn't your predicate take two arguments? +1 for lambda :)

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you want to sort the elements of some container (of your own design) for different versions of how to compare between these elements? If so, just provide your sorting algorithms with the comparison functor/function.